# Was inspector Lui in a prison or mental institution?

Tags: plot-explanation, firestorm

I saw the Honk Kong action film [Firestorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm_%282013_film%29) with subtitles and have a doubt regarding the ending scene.

At the end, Inspector Lui was debriefing another officer and smiling to himself, then the camera panned out and an iron door of a cell where they were sitting came into view. Was it a jail or a mental institution or somewhere else?

Comment: There is no need for adding the movie title into the question title (as it is already in the tags and the question body) and you should refrain from it if it hidners the reading flow. If you have to include it, do it in a natural and stream-lined way please. See the [respective meta discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1087/49) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liu is in jail for the crimes he committed while taking Nam down.  Throughout the beginning of the movie he does everything "by the book", but by the end he is forced to forgoe the rules and has to go to jail as a result.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to be sure, coz he was smiling to himself, so I thought with all that shoot out he had probably lost it! So he admitted his crimes himself, even though all the witnesses against his crimes were dead?

Comment: There's no way to know for sure, but his character is constantly struggling with morals so it's likely he came clean about what happened.  As for why he's smiling, all I can think is that he felt that Nam's death was worth the punishment.